# The difference between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following (working) JavaScript datepicker. The "out" mindate is equal to 1. How can I make the "out" mindate to equal to the difference between the my visitor-selected in date and today's date instead of just 1?

```
$(function() { var dateSelected = false;

$( "#in" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        dateSelected = true;

    }
});

$('form').submit(function(){
    if (!dateSelected) {
        alert('Please Enter start Dates');
    }
    return dateSelected;
});
});

$(function() { var dateSelected = false;


$( "#out" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        dateSelected = true;

    }
});
$('form').submit(function(){
    if (!dateSelected) {
        alert('Please Enter end Dates');
    }
    return dateSelected;
});
});
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference between the out and in date in days like this:

```
var nDifference = Math.abs(new Date($("#in").val()) - new Date());
var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var days = Math.round(nDifference / one_day);
```

and set the **min date** like:

```
minDate: days;​
```

Comment: Hi Palash, i am so sorry its actually the difference between the "in" date and todays date. Can u help me change the code please. and where do i put the first 3 lines of codes. I am really lost. Appreciate it

Comment: Sorry boss, it didn't work, maybe i place the first 3 line of codes in the wrong place. Where shoud i put it?

Comment: May i know where i should place the first 3 lines of codes....it is not working,,,